# Windows update: What updates are included in a Rollup update?

Tags: windows-update, wsus

I will try to explain my concern with an example from windows 8.1 updates of August 2020.

In wsus I can see:

- Security Only Update for .NET Framework 3.5, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1,
  4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8 for Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB4570502)
- Security and Quality Rollup for .NET Framework 3.5, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8 for Windows 8.1, RT 8.1, and Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB4570508)

Common sense suggests that the second one includes the first, but in the documentation I cannot find any evidence. Where should I check to be sure a "security only" is completely included inside a "Security and Quality" update of the same release date ?

Thanks
Filippo

Comment: "security and quality" means it includes both security and quality updates, all of them. I can't see why you'd need more evidence.

Comment: I wouldn't like to rely only on the title before discarding and update. Wsus reports both to be necessary, it is correct but it is a bit confusing: in reality after installing **Security and Quality** the corresponding **Security Only** is not needed. Anyway for my peace of mind I would read somewhere that **KB4570508** contains **KB4570502**. Is it explicitly written somewhere ?

Comment: I think WSUS reports both as necessary because both contain the security updates. You could approve the security update first, and then see if the quality update is still recommended, which it might be. Then it is just up to you if you want to deploy the additional package or not. If you search the KB article on Microsoft, you can get release notes for each update. Both of these updates contain patches for CVE-2020-1476 and CVE-2020-1046. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4570502/kb4570502 and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4570508/kb4570508